# High ACPI interrupts counts in brand-new laptop

Tags: 14.04, acpi

EDIT:

It almost seems like the issue is resolved now(I get 22 interrupts in a 10 seconds interval with video playing in the background). The only difference is that I re-installed Ubuntu, but this time I fully formatted the SSD and changed the partitioning scheme to msdos(I'm assuming it was a GPT before, because I wasn't able to properly set-up grub to boot from the SSD).

I'll keep an eye on the interrupts in the upcoming restarts and see if the issue persists.

---

Laptop model: Asus K750 Series

Exact model number: K750LN-T4155

I'm not a 100% sure, but I believe this has been going on since I first installed Ubuntu(that was the first thing I installed on the laptop - it's brand new)

The only difference from the original hardware, is that I added-in a 128 GB SSD in addition to the 1 TB HDD that comes with the laptop.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with all of the available updates installed

---

Within a couple of minutes after a restart, the following command

`cat /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all`

Yields the astonishing `22010550`

Running `cat /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all && sleep 10 && cat /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe_all` Yields this:

`22010550
22504544`

That's **`493994`**(yes, almost half a million!) interrupts in merely 10 seconds. I'm pretty sure that's not normal. 
This was the result while Google Chrome is running with 6 tabs open - without it running, for 10 seconds, I get `540859` - even more, so it shouldn't be a problem of a program that's running(I have chrome and a terminal open + some server-related services in the background: php5, mysql, nginx, etc.).

I tried everything suggested here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReschedulingInterrupts under the "Troubleshooting ACPI and APIC problems" - none of those helped, some even made booting not possible.

Due to another issue with this laptop(the fn keys not being recognized), I tried running one of the latest kernel builds, namely `3.16.3-031603.201409171435_amd64` - the issue still persisted.

I have the latest BIOS version(it's technically the first release - there has been no update for it yet).

I'm ready to provide any additional information necessary, I'm just not sure what I should be posting.

As a result of the constant interrupts, one of the kworker threads is using(reported by the Gnome System Monitor) between 10 and 12% CPU at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue is resolved in linux core upstream - due to my other issues I've been trying the latest mainline kernels and that's when I no longer have the high interrupt counts.

Right now I'm running the `v3.17-rc6-utopic` kernel( http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17-rc6-utopic/ ) - what I tried running before was the 3.16.3 build, but that was like 6 releases older than the 3.17 RC 6 version - it seems the issue got fixed somewhere inbetween.

In order to test a mainline kernel, you can follow the directions from this wiki page - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: For anyone else that stumbles upon this, I opened a bug report(since it almost seems like it could be a regression). You can follow the report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1406767